# How to draw bottom half of a circle in canvas

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw the the bottom half of the circle using the appropriate x=cos(theta), y=sin(theta) functions. If I iterate theta from Math.PI to 2*Math.PI I seem to be getting the upper half of the circle instead:

[image]

What am I doing wrong in this code snippet:

```
    window.onload = function() 
    {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('circle-canvas');

        if (canvas && canvas.getContext) {
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            if (context) {
                context.strokeStyle = "#369";
                context.lineWidth = 4;


                j = canvas.width / 2;
                k = canvas.height / 2;
                r = canvas.width / 4; 

                function computeX(theta, r, j, k){ return r * Math.cos(theta) + j; }
                function computeY(theta, r, j, k){ return r * Math.sin(theta) + k; }

                start = Math.PI;
                context.lineTo(computeX(start, r, j, k), computeY(start, r, j, k));
                for(var theta = start; theta <= (2*Math.PI); theta += .1) 
                {
                    x = computeX(theta, r, j, k);
                    y = computeY(theta, r, j, k),

                    context.lineTo(x, y);
                }
                context.stroke();
                context.closePath();
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
I am aware of the arc function. I need to implement the arc this way because this will be used as part of a bigger problem where I need to compute each individual point of the arc.

Comment: Why do you expect to get the lower half circle? Compare the coordinate system normally used and the one used on the canvas (is increasing y coordinate going up or down?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put a - before r

```
y = computeY(theta, -r, j, k),
```

Tested and it works

Comment: It does work, but do you know why it works? It feels more like a hack.

Comment: it puts the world location to a negative.

Comment: @Ramin On a canvas, 0,0 is the top left corner. You were assuming bottom right. This corrects it.

Answer (score 9):

There is an `arc`function.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("circle-canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var centerX = canvas.width / 2; 
var centerY = canvas.height / 4; 

var radius = canvas.width / 4; 

// I think these values are the angles for the bottom half - otherwise use other values
var startingAngle = Math.PI;
var endingAngle = 0;
var counterclockwise = true;

context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startingAngle,
    endingAngle, counterclockwise);

context.lineWidth = 4;
context.strokeStyle = "#369";
context.stroke();
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a function to do just do for you, [`arc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Arcs).

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.arc(256, 128, 128, Math.PI, 0, true);
context.stroke();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9mAq5/

Answer (score 4):

<strike>You need to change the start to `0`, and the end point to `Math.Pi`</strike>

Not quite sure why, but it appears that canvas goes clockwise, not anticlockwise.

See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kvAzb/1/

Above solution works, but it not the correct solution. New solution below:

**EDIT**

Aha, Roger's comment explains it. Canvas coordinates start with 0,0 as the top-left corner, not the bottom-left corner. You therefore need to flip your `computeY` function.

`function computeY(theta, r, j, k){ return r * Math.sin(theta) + k; }`

changes to

`function computeY(theta, r, j, k){ return canvas.height - (r * Math.sin(theta) + k); }`

Comment: Forgot about that quirk. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

quick guess, try changing the sign(if you're using positive relative coords, try using negatives)