# How to insert half circle style marker in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Is it possible to insert half circle shape like below?

[image]

I'd like to use it as a vector point marker.

[RegularShape](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/regularshape.html) goes close to my intention but it seems to work only for "regular shapes".

I've found also an example using [Icon](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/examples/earthquake-custom-symbol.html) which looks very useful and I can achieve a similar result with polygons.
Is there any smarter way?

What about using Point instead of Polygon and masking the other half?
Thanks.

Comment: How did you achieve with `RegularShape`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Icon`... Thank you for pointing out my error! I edited the question as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like in the [example](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/earthquake-custom-symbol.html) you found, you can create a canvas and use it as `img` of an `icon` style:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = size;
canvas.height = size;
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 4;
var radius = canvas.width / 4;
var startingAngle = Math.PI / 2;
var endingAngle = -Math.PI / 2;
var counterclockwise = false;
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startingAngle,
    endingAngle, counterclockwise);
context.fillStyle = '#bada55';
context.fill();
style = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    img: canvas,
    imgSize: [size, size]
  })
});
```

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r1zc4jdw/) which shows the above code in action.

The circle creation code is based on an answer from [How to draw bottom half of a circle in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312922/how-to-draw-bottom-half-of-a-circle-in-canvas).

Comment: Just a great demo!

Comment: The JSFiddle no longer works: 

<a class='gotoLine' href='#87:14'>87:14</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: ol is not defined"